# Modify values of a string in c

Tags: c, string, replace

I am trying to change the characters in a string using a for loop, here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
char h[] = "ABCDEFGH";
printf("h : %s\n", h);
int i = 0;
for(i; i<sizeof(h)-1; i++){
    printf("i : %i\n", i);
    printf("Starting value : %d\n", h[i]);
    h[i] = "A";
    printf("Test replace h[%u] : %d\n", i, h[i]);
}
printf("Final product : %s\n", h);
}
```

Here is my output:

```
h : ABCDEFGH
i : 0
Starting value : 65
Test replace h[0] : 117
i : 1
Starting value : 66
Test replace h[1] : 117
i : 2
Starting value : 67
Test replace h[2] : 117
i : 3
Starting value : 68
Test replace h[3] : 117
i : 4
Starting value : 69
Test replace h[4] : 117
i : 5
Starting value : 70
Test replace h[5] : 117
i : 6
Starting value : 71
Test replace h[6] : 117
i : 7
Starting value : 72
Test replace h[7] : 117
Final product : uuuuuuuu
```

Why are the values at each index integers (forcing me to use %d instead of %s)?
What do those numbers represent?
Why is the final product "uuuuuuuu" instead of "AAAAAAAA"? and how can I change the code to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing strings (double quotes, which are 0-terminated arrays of characters represented as pointers to the first character) with characters (single quotes, which are small integers).

This:

```
h[i] = "A";
```

should have given you a serious compiler warning. You should enable and check all warnings.

It should be:

```
h[i] = 'A';
```

to assign a new character value. What your code does is take the address of the constant string `"A"` (remember: double quotes are strings) and smash that into the single character `h[i]`. The result is unpredictable.

Single characters are printed either as themselves with `%c`, or as integers with e.g. `%d`:

```
printf("on this machine, 'A' is %d\n", 'A');
```

The above will print `65` on many current-day computers, since the character encoding value used to represent the letter `'A'` is 65 in ASCII and Unicode.

Comment: @Thomas Same here, need to work on the words-per-minute performance ;).

Comment: @Thomas Luckily, practice is free! :)

Comment: Please don't teach casts, in particular none that are completely redundant. `'A'` is an integer by definition in C, and even if it were not, narrow types are always promoted to `int` for `printf` and similar.

Comment: @JensGustedt It was for the signedness issue, since `%d` requires (signed) `int` but `char` has undefined sign.

Comment: It's *not* a char to start with. So there's no signedness issue.

Comment: @unwind, and even if it would be `unsigned char` it would be promoted to `int`.

Comment: @JensGustedt Great, I wasn't sure about that. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The type of an element of array h is `char` while the type of string literal `"A"` is `char[2]`. That is string literals are character arrays. When the name of an array is used in expressions it is converted to a pointer to its first element. So your program has undefined behaviour because an object of type char can not represent the value of pointer,

You could use character literal `'A'` instead of the string literal `"A"`. For example

```
h[i] = 'A';
```

Or you could use the string literal but take only one its element. For example

```
h[i] = "A"[0];
```

or

```
h[i] = *"A";
```